# Change highlight colors in omnibox in google chrome theme manifest.json

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

Can I change the highlight color in the omnibox? If so, can I change the color of the text that is highlighted? What element(s) should I be using? The default colors are a dark blue for the highlight color and white for the highlighted text color.

(I am making a google chrome theme.)

Answer (score 0):

[Themes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes) can customize [some of the colors](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=symbol:kOverwritableColorTable%5Cb) of the omnibox, specifically text and background, not the highlight.

P.S. Extensions can't do it.

Comment: Too bad Chrome doesn't use accent colors to highlight omnibox text like it does on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do have control over the omnibox color. On Mac OS it is the accent color that defines it. On windows it is the accent color but you need to enable the accent color in the title bars and window borders option.